# Jquery-fileupload get original file size before resizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, client-side, image-resizing

I am using [blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) plugin to upload and resize the images on client side on my website.

I need a way to get origonal uploaded image dimensions before it is resized to my provided values in **imageMaxWidth and imageMaxHeight** options.

Any help or guidance will be great, or i can edit the library and add this hook if it is not already there to return original file data.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Found any solution which might help?

Comment: added the hook in the library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just discovered something without adding custom hooks:

Just override add method and calculate image dimensions from file object as such:

```
add: function(e, data) {
var img = new Image;
var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
img.onload = function() {
  sizes =
    width: this.width
    height: this.height
};
img.src = _URL.createObjectURL(data.files[0]);

//below code is to let the library further process file e.g resize etc
var $this = $(this);
return data.process(function() {
  return $this.fileupload('process', data);
}).done(function() {
  return data.submit();
});
```

}

And here you have it, in the sizes hash.

Cheers!